# CSS is not linking to HTML

Tags: html, css

I know it's been asked and I've compared my code to what others have posted but I haven't had any luck fixing it!

My assignment requires that I use XHTML and external style CSS.The HTML works but the CSS is not being applied to the webpage. I've tried changing the DocType. Both documents are in the same folder.

This is what I have...

**HTML (index.html)**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          href="style.css" />
</head>
<!-- etc... -->
```

**CSS (style.css)**

```css
body {
    background-color: #EEE;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
    margin: 0;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
#container {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
/* etc... */
```

Comment: Is your HTML file and the CSS file in the same directory on the server?

Comment: Did you check the browser’s network console if the `style.css` is actually loaded?

Comment: No, I haven't checked the network console if it's loaded. How do I do this? :O

Comment: check the network console if the css is loaded or not, if loaded then inspect the elements also

Comment: Which os and browser you are using?

Comment: I just went to "Show Page Resources" in the Develop menu and when I click style.css, it loads.

Comment: I am using Yosemite 10.10 and Safari

Comment: please verify that index.html and style.css is at the same location

Comment: press command+alt+i it will open the developer console there click on the network tab and refresh the page it will show

Comment: @MukeshAgarwal This shortcut only works when the Develop menu is enabled. This can be done in the “Advanced” tab in the Safari preferences (“Show Develop menu in menu bar”)

Comment: No change after refreshing it ^ I have the Develop menu activated.

Comment: As stated above, index.html and style.css are in the same location

Comment: No luck with Firefox either

Comment: @AnnieThiessen So does it show up in the network console or not? In Safari, it’s called “Network Requests” which is hidden inside the “Timelines” tab.

Comment: @aaronk6, no it does not show up when I click console!

Comment: How are you browsing this? I've seen this happen if the server isn't set up to serve the CSS MIME type. Or if you're running it in a local file I think it breaks, too...

Comment: @Tim, I'm just running it as a local file for now

Comment: @AnnieThiessen Are you sure you went to the “Network Requests” view and reloaded the page after doing so?

Comment: Can you try it on a live host?

Comment: @aaronk6, yes...Timeline > Network Requests. It brings up a blank timeline...

Comment: @tim, same result on a live host. http://thiessea.myweb.cs.uwindsor.ca

Comment: Your `<link>` tag is in the body why? Move it above the `<style>` tag in your `<head>` and try it again. ( On your live site )

Comment: @Press, the <link> is in the head

Comment: @AnnieThiessen On your website it comes inside your body tag and contains all of your content.
**Edit** Okay so viewing the source shows it correctly but opening dev console it shows all your content is inside the `<link>` tag. My bad.

Comment: i misread your comment, @aaronk6. But when I refresh, the domain name, doc type (html), etc is listed at the bottom

Comment: It did the same thing for FireFox as well. The content of your page is inside the `<link>` tag. Can you put all the `<link>` text on the same line and remove the `/` at the end? I know it won't be proper xhtml without it but give it a shot? I think it has something to do with `/>`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally decided to retype the whole head and it solved the problem. So I'm assuming the problem was invisible characters in the the link tag. This must have happened when I switched from textEdit to Sublime. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score -1):

This part `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` is making your file an xml file. Just erase that. 
This link is pointing to a style.css in the same folder that your html is

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

You will need to make sure that your file is there.

Your link must have media declared. [Like this specification](http://xhtml.com/en/xhtml/reference/link/)
Well...as pointed by the guy in the comments, sorry guy, i'm new at this. You could try some standard headers http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Comment: When using the XHTML doctype, the XML prologue is perfectly valid (it’s not recommended though since it forces older IE versions into Quirks Mode). However, this isn’t the reason for the CSS being omitted, so this is why I down-voted your answer.

Comment: well. i cant comment in the question, but i think it is the media that it's not declared.